# Ext JS 4.1.3: Returning values with Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4.1

This might be a silly question, but I have been struggling with the following piece of code in my Ext JS 4.1.3 application:

```
getInvestmentFee_Percentage : function() {
    var rVal = 0;

    Ext.Ajax.request({ 
        url : 'index.php/ajax/getcountryinvestmentfeepercentage/', 
        success : function(transport, json) {
             try {
                  var JSONResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(transport.responseText);
             } catch (e) {
                  return false;
             }

             if(JSONResponse.success == true || JSONResponse.success == "true") {
                  var investTax = 1+parseFloat(JSONResponse.results[0].constantValue);
                  console.log(investTax);
                  // TODO Return investTax
                  return investTax;
             } else {
                  return false;
             }
        },
        failure : function(transport, json) {
            return false;
        }
   });

    return rVal;
}
```

I'm trying to write to the `rVal` variable, but since the `Ext.Ajax.request` is a different object, it will not do so. How do I return the value for use outside the AJAX request? I could of course write to global variables, but I doubt it's the right way to do this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot do it this way cause the `getInvestmentFee_Percentage` will (may) be exiting before the `success` or `failure` callback method gets called but anyway they are in a different scope.

So only the (a) callback method will be able to return a value, but this will be (most commonly) done in the scope of the callbackmethod. For sure you can define the callback methods within your current function but it will be all the same, your method will exit.

I guess you should rethink your implementation here.

- One approach may to use a custom event that the caller of `getInvestmentFee_Percentage` subscribe
- Or the caller of `getInvestmentFee_Percentage` sends a callback (and if required a scope) as argument which you can then use

Both would work.

Comment: Any idea on how to implement both the ways would be helpful?